# Scope usage for index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm trying to use the below scope to order my all reviews page in descending order of the review ratings . How would I implement this?
 I haved added my index method below.

```
scope :order_by_rating, ->{left_joins(:reviews).group(:id).order('avg(rating) desc')}
```

```
      def index

        if @tea = Tea.find_by_id(params[:tea_id])
          @reviews = @tea.reviews
        else
          @reviews = Review.all
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please change your scope to

```
scope :order_by_rating, ->{group(:id).order('avg(reviews.rating) desc')}
```

Comment: using my method apparently doesnt do anything but when I use the second logic that is the same as my method I get  Can't join 'Review' to association named 'review'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: try replacing .order('avg(rating) desc'
with .order('avg(reviews.rating) desc'